# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una condición que me envíe un msj a mi vista?

Tags: php, html, laravel, oracle

Lo que realizo una importación de datos a mi base de datos, lo que quiero es que si al seleccionar un archivo que no sea de **xsl** de excel y al enviarlo me tire un msj que el archivo es incorrecto ya puedo enviar un msj que cuando el archivo se me envía me muestra el msj que el archivo cargó correctamente

**Este es mi controlador donde importo los datos y mando el mensaje a mi vista**

```
  class importarexcel extends Controller
{


    public function cargar_datos_usuarios(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        Excel::Import(new Usersimport, $file);
        return back()->with('message', 'Importacion de usuarios completado')->withError('error_message', 'ERROR AL SUBIR ARCHIVO');
    }


}
```

y esta es mi vista donde muestro el mensaje que envío

```
 <div class="box-body" >

            <form action="{{route('cargar_datos_usuarios')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                @csrf
                @if(Session::has('message'))
                    <p>{{Session::get('message')}}</p>
                @else
                    <p>{{Session::get('error_message')}}</p>
                @endif

                <h5>Seleccione el archivo</h5>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="archivo"/>.
                <br><br>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">ENVIAR</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>
```

Por ejemplo este es el error que quiero que no me muestre de esta forma si no que se me quede en la pagina que esta y ahi me muestre el mensaje hay tal erro o problemas al subir el archivo y no que me muestre este errro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el controlador modificalo de esta forma, usando la validación de laravel `use Validator;` y haciendo una condicional en caso de errores:

```
use Validator;

class importarexcel extends Controller
 {
 public function cargar_datos_usuarios(Request $request)
  {
    $file = $request->file('file');

    $validator = Validator::make(
        [
            'file'      => $file,
            'extension' => strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
        ],
        [
            'file'          => 'required',
            'extension'     => 'required|in:xlsx,xls',
        ],
        [   
            'extension.in'    => 'Error al subir archivo, extensión invalida.',
        ]
      );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validator->getMessageBag());
    } else {
        return back()->with('message', 'Importacion de usuarios completado.');
    }
   }
 }
```

Esta sería tu vista, solo debes modificar tu `if` agregando `else`, que es lo que se ejecutara si no se cumple la condición inicial:

```
     @csrf
     @if($errors->any())
         {{ implode('', $errors->all(':message')) }}
     @else
         <p>{{Session::get('message')}}</p>
     @endif
```

Te recomiendo siempre verificar la documentación oficial de laravel y depurar tus variables para saber cual es el error o si tu `data` llega correctamente, en laravel se suele usar `dd($variable)`.

Comment: Pero en el controlador como pondria el mensaje por que ahi lo que le indico es que al no cumplirse la primera me muestre el mensaje other_message pero este me lo traera del controlador y es ahi que no se como modificar el codigo para que me envie otro mensaje

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, puedes intentarlo así.

Comment: ahorita lo modifique como indicaste pero me tira el error que no quiero me muestre de esa forma si no que se quede en la misma pantalla y que ahi me muestre algun tipo de mensaje que si no se carga o hay algun problema me indique problemas al subir el archivo o algo asi ahi modifique el codigo como me dijiste pero no me carga el mensaje

Comment: Edite nuevamente, esta sería una forma mas sencilla, inténtalo y déjame saber si te funcionó.

Comment: Ahi modifique el codigo y me funciona solo si se cargan los archivos me muestra el mensaje se subieron correctemente pero cuando le doy un error al documento no me toma el error para mostrarlo como mensaje si no que me sigue igual  ahi modifique el codigo para que lo mires

Comment: Recuerda leer la documentación de laravel, allí encuentras la información mas clara, edité nuevamente, inténtalo de esta forma.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda eso me funciono

Comment: Ten en cuenta en que momento ingresan los datos a tu base, fíjate que debes agregar `Excel::Import(new Usersimport, $file);` ya que yo no lo use en mi ejemplo y tu lo tenias inicialmente.

Comment: Si eso me fije y estaba asi hasta que lo note pero funciona muy bien una vez le agrego el Excel::Import(new Usersimport, $file); en la condicion si es la extension correcta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una validación para el archivo que recibes de la siguiente forma:

```
$request->validate([
  'file' => 'file|mimes:xls,xlsx'
]);
```

Esto validará el archivo y devolverá un mensaje de error que lo puedes mostrar en la vista.

Para más información te recomiendo que leas la documentación de laravel para manejar validaciones.

[Laravel - Validación](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#introduction)

Comment: esta validacion iria en mi controlador me imagino estuve viendo la documentacion pero no se como adaptarlo a mi codigo